# How to route new wiring into main panel from attic via cinder block

Tags: electrical-panel

I need to route at least 4 new circuits into my house. I am also performing a 200A panel upgrade since the current one is 50 years old. A problem I have is that the hole where the wires go into panel from the cinder block is full and I'd need to create a new method in bringing new circuits from the attic into the panel.

Attic space is 3 feet directly above panel (wooden panel area) with the cables entering through the bottom of the panel via cinder block hole. State is AZ inside Maricopa county which enforces NEC 2017 code
Picture: [image]

My thoughts were

1. Drilling a new vertical hole into the blocks besides the existing, but I only have 8 inches or so of clearance in the attic so it would be difficult to get a drill bit in there. The total length is around 3 feet from the attic entry to the bottom of the service panel.
2. Drill a horizontal hole that goes into the garage and run the individual THHN wires up into the attic inside conduit. This would have a negative appeal inside the garage due to spacing.
3. Don't drill into the concrete at all and run the THHN wires vertically into the attic via conduit and then have a few junction boxes that connect them into their associated romex NM cable.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that Rule of Six panel needs to disappear.  Is there any place indoors that would be fit for a subpanel?  (in a threshold or hallway where no one is likely to block the 30 x 36" working space)

Comment: No, unfortunately except for the garage.