# How to install a meter combo panel that is already too high (6'7") per NEC

Tags: electrical-panel, panel

I have an existing, detached breaker panel and service box that are connected with a nipple. I want to replace it with a single combo meter that can support solar such as the Siemens MC4040S1200SC. The problem is that the existing panel boxes are both too high and I can't just mount my new panel in place. If I did, then the top of the highest breaker would be close to 7'9" which violates the code. Thus, I figure I need to cut the PVC housing off the service entrance cables and shorten them by about 2 feet. I just haven't seen anyone doing this online. How else would I be able to fit a bigger panel in?

I also have another problem of the short wires in the back of the existing panel box which are poked through a hole in the concrete. I figure I'd need to route them to an external weatherproof box and make splices there to feed them lower into the new breaker panel.

Please see pic attached.

[image]

Comment: "figure I need to cut the PVC housing off the service entrance cables and shorten them by about 2 feet." - why do you think that's a big deal? Electricians do it all the time.

Comment: I know meter mains are a thing now, but is there any big reason you can't just install a new panel and keep the meter as is? The feed comes out near the bottom of the meter box and then loops to the top of the panel - if you mount your new panel lower then you solve the height problem and the feed is more direct to the top of the new panel.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I want to do solar next thus I was only looking at solar-ready meter/breaker combos. If I move the breaker panel lower, then I would have to create a new knockout in the back of the panel to allow the current wires is. I suppose tho this is probably my only way forward.

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/239766/how-to-route-new-wiring-into-main-panel-from-attic-via-cinder-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trim the conduit riser is not a difficult thing:

1. Ask power company to disconnect the conductors.
2. Remove meter base etc.
3. Consider sliding a protective sleeve over the conductors and insert into the existing conduit. That could take the form of a smaller piece of pipe or conduit, a bit of sheet metal rolled around the conductors, etc. Anything to protect the conductors (either as a group or individually) while you're cutting the outer conduit.
4. Cut the conduit carefully.

If there's sufficient room you may be able to keep the existing breaker panel and place your new meter/main box where the meter base sits now. The existing panel would be reconfigured as a sub-panel. It might also be possible to position the new meter/main box below the existing panel -- but check whether the power utility has requirements as to the minimum elevation of the meter above ground.

You may also consider moving the conduit and service wires a few inches or even a foot to improve alignment of the new panel to the bundle of wires through the wall and the incoming service. The easiness or difficulty of this depends on whether the conductors are direct-buried or encased in conduit for their full run, whether moving the riser would require shortening or lengthening the service conductors, whether the ground below is simple landscape or covered with concrete, etc.